# Calculating the sum of previous rows in a column in a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm having some trouble calculating the sum of all previous rows in a column in a data structure like `DataTable`

For example, we have a table with columns **"Waiting Time"** and **"Burst Time"**.

Waiting Time's row values must be calculated by taking the values from previous rows in the Burst Time column(*if there are such a.k.a its not the first row that we are calculating values for currently*)

How can I achieve that? Is it as simple as using `Compute()` and passing an appropriate filter string?

EDIT: An example of what I want to do.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you have already tried, please?

Comment: Just `Sum(Burst Time column)` but obviously that doesn't work as it sums a total,not just values from previous rows.

Comment: Again, it is much better to see exact example, maybe with real tables and data inside them, plus your code. One more thing: what do you mean by "previous rows"? Do you have time field or something else that could be used to create "previous" logic?

Comment: I have edited my original post with a simple example of what I wanna do. The first row has values 2 and 0,respectively. The next row's value for the Waiting Time is calculated by summing all the previous row values for the burst time.

Comment: Your target is clear, what has been asked is to see what you tried so far. It's easier to help from there :)

Comment: I call the `Compute()` method on my DataTable like this: `double waitTime = Convert.ToDouble(ready.Compute("Sum(Burst_Time)", string.Empty));` Thats all I've tried up until now, I have no idea what else to try, thats why I'm asking on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made an example. Have now idea how you populate DataTable, that is why I came up with hardcoded one.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dataSet = new DataSet();
        var dataTable = MakeTable();
        var columns = dataTable.Columns;

        Console.WriteLine("Defined Table");
        PrintDataTable(dataTable);

        foreach (DataRow dataTableRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var id = dataTableRow["ID"];
            var burstTime = dataTable.Compute("Sum(BurstTime)", $"ID < {id}");
            dataTableRow["WaitingTime"] = burstTime;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Table After Operation");
        PrintDataTable(dataTable);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dataTableRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{dataTableRow["Id"]}\t\t| {dataTableRow["WaitingTime"]}\t\t| {dataTableRow["BurstTime"]}");
        }
    }

    private static DataSet dataSet;

    private static DataTable MakeTable()
    {
        // Create a new DataTable.
        DataTable table = new DataTable("childTable");
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;

        // Create first column and add to the DataTable.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "ID";
        column.AutoIncrement = true;
        column.Caption = "ID";
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column.Unique = true;

        // Add the column to the DataColumnCollection.
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create second column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "ChildItem";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "ChildItem";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create third column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "ParentID";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "ParentID";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create third column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "WaitingTime";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "WaitingTime";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        // Create fourth column.
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        column.ColumnName = "BurstTime";
        column.AutoIncrement = false;
        column.Caption = "BursTime";
        column.ReadOnly = false;
        column.Unique = false;
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

        // Create three sets of DataRow objects, 
        // five rows each, and add to DataTable.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = i;
            row["ChildItem"] = "Item " + i;
            row["ParentID"] = 0;
            row["WaitingTime"] = 0;
            row["BurstTime"] = i;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = i + 5;
            row["ChildItem"] = "Item " + i;
            row["ParentID"] = 1;
            row["WaitingTime"] = 0;
            row["BurstTime"] = i + 5;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = i + 10;
            row["ChildItem"] = "Item " + i;
            row["ParentID"] = 2;
            row["WaitingTime"] = 0;
            row["BurstTime"] = i + 10;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

The most interesting for you, I suppose:

```
foreach (DataRow dataTableRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    var id = dataTableRow["ID"];
    var burstTime = dataTable.Compute("Sum(BurstTime)", $"ID < {id}");
    dataTableRow["WaitingTime"] = burstTime;
}
```

The most important here, I think, is that you have to come up with your own comparison logic, i.e. the second parameter in `Compute(string, string)` function.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I meant by calculating something from previous rows! Also,as a beginner in C#, it is interesting to find out that there is a possibility of data binding variables through the `{}` syntax of the filter parameter.

Comment: @TKD21 It is actually not a data binding. It is a [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to build a string for the filter value.